# work the service based upon datetime parameteric caluclations by using c# window service

Tags: c#, windows-services

Here I below pasted code I'm using in current window service solution, this will run job every day 10 AM regularly, I will pass the parameters using App.configuaration file

APP.CONFIG

```xml
<add key ="FIREHOST_TIME" value ="10" ></add>
<add key ="SETDAYS" value ="1" ></add>
```

CODE BEHIND PAGE

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

     DateTime tenAM = DateTime.Today.AddHours(FIREHOST_TIME);



      if (DateTime.Now > tenAM)
          tenAM = tenAM.AddDays(SETDAYS);


      // calculate milliseconds until the next 10:00 AM.  
      int timeToFirstExecution = (int)tenAM.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

      // calculate the number of milliseconds in 24 hours.   
      int timeBetweenCalls = (int)new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0).TotalMilliseconds;

      TimerCallback methodToExecute = kickstart;

      // start the timer.  The timer will execute "ProcessFile" when the number of seconds between now and   
      // the next 10:00 AM elapse.  After that, it will execute every 24 hours.   
      System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(methodToExecute, null, timeToFirstExecution, timeBetweenCalls);


}
```

Now I am trying to run my service, based up on the below Mentioned conditions:

I want to start my service but it should job perform the job based on the this new tag which I will add newly in app.config

```
BY based on above four tags

if RUN_NOW == 1

    has to perform service based on FIREHOST_TIME and SETDAYS normal thing

else 

    service have to perform the Job doing by after 5 days(because WAIT_DAYS = 5) 
    then it have to use the FIREHOST_TIME and SETDAYS value
```

Note: service should not get stopped, it should be in started condition only

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why don't you do this with scheduled task? You can even launch then manually if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how you want implement the whole program logic, the portion I can try to help you is about reacting to a config file modification without restarting the service, this can be done with:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("thesectiontorefresh");
```

for a better work, you can call this with a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) listening for someone modifying the app.config file and react properly after calling the refresh as show above. You can obtain the configuration file path with this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

As a general information, consider to redesign the way you are solving the problem by using system scheduled task instead of writing your own service.